# Provide global configuration in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

currently i provide my application with a constant called "config" to inject some specific application-wide configuration like the API endpoint URL and so on.

This works like expected for my main module "app" in the configuration section.

```
app.config(['config', function(config) {
    console.log(config.api); // http://api.endpoint.com
}];
```

The problem is, that i have a separate module like "app.auth" where i wish you configure it with some values from this global constant, but there i get an error, that the config is unknown.

How i can solve this? Inject a service in the configuration area isn't a solution because AngularJS don't provide the services on the configuration block.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not an answer, but you can use the `$rootScope` to store your config

Comment: if your `config` injectable is an Angular constant (you defined it with `angular.module().constant()`), then you should have no problem injecting this into other config blocks provided you set up module dependencies correctly. [`constant`s are valid for injection into config blocks](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module/#module-loading-dependencies).

Comment: From my point of view this isn't a solution, the $rootScope is not a trash ;) - Nevertheless thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

First off you answer your question about why 'config' is not available to your app.
Is your app set as a dependency of 'app.auth'?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);
var authApp = angular.module('myApp.auth', ['myApp']);
```

Secondly using a constant to set multiple values is a poor use of constant, that would be a great job for a provider. Here is an example:

```
module.provider('GlobalConfig', function ($resourceProvider) {
    var valOne = 'Some Default';
    this.setOne = function(value) {
        valOne = value;
    };

    var valTwo = 'Another Default';
    this.setTwo = function(value) {
        valTwo = value;
    };

    this.$get = function($resource) {
        return {
            getOne: function() {
                return valOne;
            },
            getTwo: function() {
                return valTwo;
            }
        };
    };

});
```

From a .config the provider above can be injected by using 'GlobalConfigProvider' and only the setters would be available. Then for directives and services 'GlobalConfig' can be injected and only the getters would be available.

Comment: I didn't know that the getter's are only available in directives and services, thank you for the hint. The problem is, that i want to configure some other providers like me $resourceProvider or $authenticationProvider with some information about the implemented REST API.

Comment: To clarify the functions defined in the $get of the provider are only available from the actual class. The functions and values defined on 'this' of the provider are only available when injecting  'xProvider', you could also expose the getters there as well.

Comment: From a provider you can also inject other providers. I updated the example provider to show how you can inject $resourceProvider and  $resource.